# Concise Ruby hash equivalent of Python dict.get()

Tags: python, ruby, dictionary, hash

In know that I can manipulate a Ruby default `Hash` value like this:

```
h={a:1, b:2, c:3}
h[:x] # => nil
h.default = 5
h[:x] # => 5
h.default = 8
h[:y] # => 8
```

but this gets quite tedious when doing it repeatedly for multiple values with different defaults.

It also could get dangerous if the hash is passed to other methods which want their own defaults for certain (potentially missing) keys.

In Python, I used to

```
d={'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
d.get('x', 5) # => 5
d.get('y', 8) # => 8
```

which doesn't have any side-effects. Is there an equivalent of this `get` method in Ruby?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it is called [`fetch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch), and it can also take a block:

```
h.fetch(:x, 5)
h.fetch(:x) {|missing_key| "Unfortunately #{missing_key} is not available"}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `#fetch` is to simply do something like this:

```
h[:x] || 5
```

In Python missing keys will raise a KeyError, but in Ruby missing keys simply return nil.

This has a subtly different meaning, because the default will happen if either:

1. the key is not in the hash
2. the key's value in the hash is already `nil`

whereas fetch will only make an impact in scenario 1.

The closest Python equivalent of this code is

```
h.get('x') or 5
```

(Note though that this is still different since truthiness/falsiness is different in Python than in Ruby)

Comment: 3. the key's value in the hash is already `false`. So your answer isn't equivalent at all to `dict.get()`

Comment: I specifically mentioned that it's not equivalent. The point is it achieves what might be your goal with fetch, and in circumstances where the behavior is correct, it's more idiomatic. Some usages of Python's dict.get don't call for fetch while others do