# How to correctly check for nested values in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I have a ruby hash that looks like this:

```
payload = {
  "fields" => {
    "publishedDate" => {
      "de"=>"2019-05-02T00:00+02:00"
    }
  }
}
```

So now I want to access the date. How would I efficiently and correctly write an if statement to check if the date exists?

I'm currently doing something like this but it somehow feels like it is too much code:

```
payload["fields"] && payload["fields"]["publishedDate"] && payload["fields"]["publishedDate"].first && payload["fields"]["publishedDate"].first.last
```

Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20258699/5671433. This should help. You'll have to do something like `payload.fetch(:fields, {}).fetch('publishedDate', {})` and so on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the date is always the value (taking the example of `de`), then you can use [`dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Hash.html#method-i-dig) to reach every `publishedDate`, then [`Hash#values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Hash.html#method-i-values) to for every hash/value and `any?(&:present?)` to check if any of the given values is not *blank*:

```
(payload.dig('fields', 'publishedDate') || {}).values.any?(&:present?)
```

In the eventual case that fields and/or publishedDate aren't present in the hash, it'll return nil, and you'll use {} to invoke values, resulting in an empty array with no *`present?`* values.

If the hash comes from a request params, you must know that Rails invokes `with_indifferent_access` on the object and your hash keys are accessible as symbols as well, so you could do:

```
(payload.dig(:fields, :publishedDate) || {}).values.any?(&:present?)
```

Comment: Didn’t know about dig but that’s exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much Sebastian!

Comment: Is there also a way to dig for different keys like publishedDate and publishAt? Or do I have indeed to have use multiple digs for that? Thank you!

Comment: You could store `dig('fields')` in a variable and then check if they're present in your hash, although if you're passing a single `key` it'd be better to use `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [values_at](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/values_at) method with [dig](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/dig). It will simplify your more advanced need also.

```
(payload.dig('fields', 'publishedDate') || {}).values_at('de').any?(&:present?)
```

Through the above solution, you can validate your particular key also. You can also include multiple keys inside your **values_at** method like

```
(payload.dig('fields', 'publishedDate') || {}).values_at('de', 'month', 'year').any?(&:present?)
```